# How to handle hyphens in GraphQL Schema definitions

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, graphql, mongoose-schema, graphql-js

My mongoose schema is as follows

```
var ImageFormats = new Schema({
     svg        : String,
     png-xlarge : String,
     png-small  : String
});
```

When I translate this into a GraphQL Schema, this is what I try

```
export var GQImageFormatsType: ObjectType = new ObjectType({
     name: 'ImageFormats',

     fields: {
          svg        : { type: GraphQLString },
         'png-xlarge': { type: GraphQLString },
         'png-small' : { type: GraphQLString }
 }
});
```

GraphQL Returns the following error: `Error: Names must match /^[_a-zA-Z][_a-zA-Z0-9]*$/ but "png-xlarge" does not.`

If I am trying to model the GraphQL after my Mongoose model, how can I reconcile the fields? Is there a way for me to create an alias?

(I have searched for this on the graffiti and stackoverflow forums but could not find a similar question)

Comment: in your code above (mongoose schema), you don't declare `png-lg` property

Comment: @Medet_Tleukabiluly Sorry I pasted the wrong error message. It does indeed reference the mongoose schema's png-xlarge property. Any thoughts?

Comment: Try explicitly defining default value for mongoose schema, `png-xlarge : { type: String, default: '' }`, probably mongoose null values differ from GraphQLString null values

Comment: @MedetTleukabiluly that doesn't work. The issue is certainly related to the field name, graphQLs code base also confirm this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> GraphQL Returns the following error: Error: Names must match /^[_a-zA-Z][_a-zA-Z0-9]*$/ but "png-xlarge" does not.

GraphQL complains that field name `'png-xlarge'` is invalid. The regular expression in error message says that the first character can be a letter irrespective of case or underscore. The remaining characters can also have digit. Therefore, it is clear that neither hyphen `-` nor single quote `'` is acceptable for a field name. The rules basically follow the variable naming rules that you find in almost every programming language. You can check the [GraphQL naming rules](https://facebook.github.io/graphql/#sec-Names).

> If I am trying to model the GraphQL after my Mongoose model, how can I reconcile the fields? Is there a way for me to create an alias?

With the help of `resolve` function, you can do this as follows:

```
pngXLarge: { 
    type: GraphQLString,
    resolve: (imageFormats) => {
        // get the value `xlarge` from the passed mongoose object 'imageFormats'
        const xlarge = imageFormats['png-xlarge'];
        return xlarge;
    },
},
```

Comment: Thanks this is perfect @ahmad-ferdous